# Window in first plan (Flex)

Tags: apache-flex

I develop an flex application and I need your help.
The window must be in foreground everytime.

I would like to know how I can catch the event when the window losts the focus and how put the window in foreground.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: This is either a usability disaster or malicious software; users will have to kill it with task manager.

Comment: No, it's a character who walk in your screen. Once by 15 minutes. And I want that the video go in foreground when it starts.
The user kill the application when he clicks on the screen or with the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is in AIR then you can use this:

Application.application.nativeWindow.alwaysInFront = true;

This will force your window to be ontop.